# Sort specific media folder with date modified

Tags: windows-explorer, mp3, sorting

I have tons of mp3s in my default Audacity folder and would like to sort them by date modified without changing the folder to general and while keeping the music info coloumns.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note:- This is on Windows 10 x64

First of all, Right Click --> Sort By --> More...

[image]

Then, scroll down till you find Date modified and check the checkbox.

[image]

Now, do the normal Sort By --> Date Modified

[image]

Now you can keep your other coloumns and can sort your media/normal folder by many more things that are available in the More... menu.

If you have any questions, please feel free to leave a comment.

Thanks to @Wendigo 's answer for helping me stumble across this.

PS:- In case you need to this for more folders, I guess [this](https://flaguser.com/2012/09/21/sorting-music-files-by-date-in-windows-7/) would work (I just stumbled across this on Google).

Answer (score 0):

Hy...try to do this : Rigth click in blank space (without columns name ) and add/quit the columns what you need in your folder

[image: capture]

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't seem to work on my computer, but I found another way and will be posting it here soon.